# Clustered index or 2 indexes on mostly read table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing, sql-server-2012-express

> Note: I use Entity Framework on SQL Server 2012, if it matters.

I have a mostly-read table, it's rarely updated. Database size is not a concern, speed is.

There is a standard PK ID field. In Selects, these two are always queried on

```
int PersonID
int NationID
```

Is it faster to query if I put an index on each individually, or a single NONCLUSTERED one on both like this:

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_mytable_Nation_person ON dbo.mytable
  (
   NationId,
   PersonId
   ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: well, what's stopping you from trying it out? generally I would say go for single index if you are always using both columns in where clause, but it depends on selectivity of per-column indexes vs. the compound index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on **how** you query.

If you have...

```
WHERE PersonID = ... AND NationID = ...
```

...use composite index.

---

If you have...

```
WHERE PersonID = ... OR NationID = ...
```

...use separate indexes.